# Translation Golf XXIX - 640 kB

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> The game is over!
>   Seems like 7 char ought to be enough for anybody, according to [Alicia's winning answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23877/translation-golf-xxix-640-kb/23881#23881).

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

Let's try something really really short:

> *640k ought to be enough for anybody.*
>
> <sub>(29 characters)</sub>

This quote is famously attributed to Bill Gates, though such attribution is often [disputed](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Bill_Gates).

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

Here's an example, non-golfed translation:

> 640 kB deberían ser suficientes para cualquiera.
>  
>  <sub>(42 characters)</sub>

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 7 caracteres

> 640k y ya.

Entiendo que no se dice lo de "a todos", a vosotros os corresponderá decidir si es aceptable o no.

EDIT: acabo de ver de dónde viene la frase en el enlace del OP. Entiendo pues que se trataría aproximadamente de una repuesta a la pregunta "¿cuánta memoria de programa es necesaria a la hora de diseñar este ordenador?", por lo tanto en el texto original en realidad creo que no es tan importante ni significativo el complemento indirecto "for anybody". Y así, la respuesta "640k y ya" sería una respuesta con el mismo significado e intención que la original.

Answer (score 5):

**10 Characters**

> 640K Bastan

Or

**12 Characters**

> 640K Alcanzan

Answer (score 3):

#### <strike>18</strike> 13 characters

> [Bastarían](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5BD5w98) 640k.

Answer (score 3):

#### <s>17</s> 11 caracteres

> 640Kb es [asaz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3vD99BM).

Comment: ¿No debería ser "son suficiente**s**"?

Answer (score 2):

## 16 caracteres

> 640k llegan a todos

Esta versión convierte un poco en afirmación la frase original, que es un condicional, pero creo que mantiene completamente el sentido. Utiliza la undécima acepción de [llegar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NV155vl):

> 11. intr. Dicho de una cantidad: **Ser suficiente**. Con medio metro más de tela llegaría para dos cortinas.

Desde luego hay una versión aun más corta (10 caracteres) que sería

> 640k llegan

Pero posiblemente toma demasiado del contexto. Podría ser que "640k llegan" para la tarea específica que quieres hacer, en lugar de "a todos nos debería llegar con tal cantidad para cualquier cosa que queramos hacer". Por eso propongo solo la primera, que creo que sí que recoge el sentido de "esta cantidad a todos nos debería ser suficiente".